# How to specifically suppress "Comparing identical expressions" in Eclipse-Helios JDT

Tags: java, eclipse, warnings, suppress-warnings, eclipse-jdt

I tried annotating the enclosing method with

```
    @SuppressWarnings("compareIdentical")
```

but this does not work (worse yet, the annotation results in its own `Unsupported @SuppressWarnings("compareIdentical")` warning!)

I know that I can always use

```
    @SuppressWarnings("all")
```

but that'd be more warning-suppression than I want.

FWIW, I got the "compareIdentical" string from the "Warning Options" table in http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_compile.htm (a hail-mary pass, to be sure).

Thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Can you post the bit of code where you perform the compare? I shouldn't know for what I should use it.

Comment: "Comparing identical expressions" happens when you set a final boolean as true and then you try some test like if(CONST==true). Or the similar but setting as false.

Comment: By the way, the fact that there is no way to surpress it seems to be an open eclipse bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=397971

Comment: Also happens with int's and maybe other types. Example: final int i = 10; if(i==10);

Comment: This is really nasty. I would like to `assert(OneModule.KNOWS_A_VALUE == OtherModule.KNOWS_THE_SAME_VALUE)` just to make sure that future adaptions of this code are done in a consistent matter. Imagine that both modules are in different libraries that might be used alone, so they can't get the knowledge from a common source. The example is of course over simplified.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Officially, there are only 3 supported arguments to `@SuppressWarnings()`, as specified by the [standard $9.6.4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.4.5):

> - Unchecked warnings (§4.8, §5.1.6, §5.1.9, §8.4.1, §8.4.8.3, §15.12.4.2, §15.13.2, §15.27.3) are specified by the string `"unchecked"`.
> - Deprecation warnings (§9.6.4.6) are specified by the string `"deprecation"`.
> - Removal warnings (§9.6.4.6) are specified by the string `"removal"`.

But, in small text, the standard mentions support for extra types:

> For other kinds of warnings, compiler vendors should document the strings they support for `@SuppressWarnings`. Vendors are encouraged to cooperate to ensure that the same names work across multiple compilers.

These are supported by some compilers:

- `all` to suppress all warnings
- `boxing` to suppress warnings relative to boxing/unboxing operations
- `cast` to suppress warnings relative to cast operations
- `dep-ann` to suppress warnings relative to deprecated annotation
- `deprecation` to suppress warnings relative to deprecation
- `fallthrough` to suppress warnings relative to missing breaks in switch statements
- `finally` to suppress warnings relative to finally block that don't return
- `hiding` to suppress warnings relative to locals that hide variable
- `incomplete-switch` to suppress warnings relative to missing entries in a switch statement (enum case)
- `nls` to suppress warnings relative to non-nls string literals
- `null` to suppress warnings relative to null analysis
- `raw` to suppress warnings relative to usage of raw types
- `restriction` to suppress warnings relative to usage of discouraged or forbidden references
- `serial` to suppress warnings relative to missing serialVersionUID field for a serializable class
- `static-access` to suppress warnings relative to incorrect static access
- `super` to suppress warnings relative to overriding a method without super invocations
- `synthetic-access` to suppress warnings relative to unoptimized access from inner classes
- `unchecked` to suppress warnings relative to unchecked operations
- `unqualified-field-access` to suppress warnings relative to field access unqualified
- `unused` to suppress warnings relative to unused code and dead code

So, there is nothing which might help you.