# How to get rid of the warning when comparing final variables?

Tags: java

As a simplified example, I have:

```
public static final int RUN_TYPE = 1;

if(RUN_TYPE == 1)
{

}
```

This gives me "Comparing identical" warning at the if. How can I get rid of this warning without disabling the "Comparing identical" warning globally?

Comment: This is a very pointless comparison.

Comment: You *could* [suppress all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996631/how-to-specifically-suppress-comparing-identical-expressions-in-eclipse-helios) warnings for that comparison, but the comparison is indeed pointless

Comment: @SachinKainth Think of something like `if (DEBUG) {}` where DEBUG is `public static final boolean DEBUG = true/false;` for example...

Comment: @Sachin: No it's not. I have to make a choice between 2 values. During development it's faster to hard-code it instead of reading a value from the console every time I run the app.

Comment: @kovacslorand If it's just for debugging/testing purposes, just make the variable non-final.

Comment: or use unit-testing and pass the desired values

Comment: The thing is that the line as it is, is literally if (1 == 1) or even if (true) depending on the compiler. Why make it final?

Comment: @Mikkel: I made it final because the value will never change after the initial assignment.

Comment: That means it will always be 1, because you can't reassign it. How could it be 2?

Comment: @TheCat: It will be 2 if I type it with my keyboard. It's a hard coded value. It can be 1 or 2, depending on what I choose before running the app.

Comment: why not just add it to a properties file or something then?

Comment: @kovacslorand But final doesn't mean that the value doesn't change, it means that it can't change. Thus the compiler knows it will always be 1, and making a comparison to 1, (ie an indication of a logic error) and thus the compiler throws a warning.

Answer (score 3):

"Comparing identical" warning is because the compiler knows the value, it knows that the RUNT_TYPE has value 1 and you are comparing it with constant 1 which doesn't makes sense.

if you compare it with another variable, which is not constant, the warning won't be there, because the value cannot be determined until runtime.

Example:

```
int ANOTHER_INT = 1;
if(RUN_TYPE == ANOTHER_INT {}
```

This won't give you "Comparing identical" warning.

Comment: @PermGenError that's what I meant

Comment: @PermGenError updated to be more specific

Answer (score 0):

Since you variable is `final` there is less than little opportunity for it to change.
Why do you need to test its value ?

**EDIT**

... then pass a property on the java command line using the `-D` flag and read this property in your code e.g.

```
if ( "WHATEVER".equals(System.getProperty("myproperty", "default_value"))) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: It's a hard-coded value on which I choose what the app will do (have two options for the variable: 1 or 2). I could do this by reading a value form the console every time I run the app, but that is tedious.